After restarting Apache IoTDB version 1.0.0 cluster, how to restore historical data that has changed to `snapshot` directory?
In Apache IoTDB version 1.0.0 and high performance cluster deployment mode, there is real-time data insert. However, after a cluster restart, all the historical data under storage group cannot be found. I checked that the disk occupied by the data directory has not disappeared, and it seems that the old data has entered the snapshot directory. The new real-time insert data continues to grow in the sequence directory. How can I restore the old data that cannot be queried?

Version 1.0 of Apache IoTDB is too old and is no longer maintained focus. It is recommended to build an Apache IoTDB version 1.3 cluster and then load your version 1.0 tsfiles nto this new cluster. The error you faced on historical data should be solved and be able to query out.
